# set the limit of the short description on the related product list

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to set the limit of the short description on the related product list.

I have done this for the product list page by using the filter:

```html
function my_filter_woocommerce_short_description( $post_excerpt )   {

    if(is_product()){


    }else{
             $post_excerpt = get_the_content();
$post_excerpt = preg_replace(" (\[.*?\])",'',$post_excerpt);
$post_excerpt = strip_shortcodes($post_excerpt);
$post_excerpt = strip_tags($post_excerpt);
$post_excerpt = substr($post_excerpt, 0, 265);
$post_excerpt = substr($post_excerpt, 0, strripos($post_excerpt, " "));
$post_excerpt = trim(preg_replace( '/\s+/', ' ', $post_excerpt));
$post_excerpt = $post_excerpt.'... <a href="'.get_permalink( $product_id ).'">more</a>';

             //$post_excerpt=substr($post_excerpt , 0 ,265);
        return $post_excerpt.'...';
    }
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_short_description','my_filter_woocommerce_short_description',10, 2 );
```

however I need to display the full short description in the product page, so inside this filter I created a if is product.
The problem is inside product page I also have a list of related products which I need to display in a short way as it is being displayed in the product list page.

How can i do it?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of the filter you used, try the action 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title' this way

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title','short_description_content', 5);

function short_description_content(){
    //code for short description content
}
```

This way, you don't need to check if it is single product or product list.

To show short description in the related product list as you said, just add 'the_excerpt' in the above function

```
function short_description_content(){
    the_excerpt();
}
```

Comment: But the problem is that I need to do the excerpt in the product page also, but only for related product list.

Comment: It's not that tough, To show short description in the related product list as you said, just add 'the_excerpt' in the above function